# Convertir de JPG a TIFF en Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, cast

Como dice el titulo, me pregunto si alguien ha convertido un bitmap o JPG a TIFF en android.

De antemano gracias.
Saludos.

Comment: Buenos días Keops, te recomiendo que pongas en que lenguaje estás desarrollando, así podrá ser posible que te contesten más rápido

Comment: Gracias, ya lo coloque en el titulo y agregue una etiqueta también sugerida

Comment: Android no es como tal un lenguaje de programación, para realizar apps en android regularmente se usa java, aunque tambien C++ o C# y otros en mucho menor medida, en que lenguaje necesitas haces la conversión, necesitamos saber porque en cada lenguaje se hace de formas muy diferentes

Comment: Correcto, a eso es lo que me refería, a que pongas el lenguaje de programación, ya que en un principio solo se desarrollaba en java, día a día otras empresas también buscan como meterse en el desarrollo móvil

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, es bueno aprender. El lenguaje es java

Answer (score 1):

Buen días, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como convertir a TIFF, el código lo saqué de este [foro](http://log.robmeek.com/2005/08/write-tiff-in-java.html) y de esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967557/java-api-to-convert-jpeg-to-tiff) de StackOverflow en inglés

```
protected boolean saveTiff(String filename, BufferedImage image) {

File tiffFile = new File(filename);
ImageOutputStream ios = null;
ImageWriter writer = null;

try {

// find an appropriate writer
Iterator it = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIF");
if (it.hasNext()) {
writer = (ImageWriter)it.next();
} else {
return false;
}

// setup writer
ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(tiffFile);
writer.setOutput(ios);
TIFFImageWriteParam writeParam = new TIFFImageWriteParam(Locale.ENGLISH);
writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
// see writeParam.getCompressionTypes() for available compression type strings
writeParam.setCompressionType("PackBits");

// convert to an IIOImage
IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(image, null, null);

// write it!
writer.write(null, iioImage, writeParam);

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return false;
}
return true;

}
```

Ahora bien, ya que el TIFF puede guardar muchas imágenes, aquí te dejo también otra [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317353/multipage-tiff-compression) de StackOverflow en inglés sobre ese tema.

Comment: Entonces debo agregar la librería de JAI imageio a mi proyecto de Android para poder utilizar las clase TIFFImageWriteParam.

Comment: La librería JAI te permitirá leer y escribir diferentes tipos de formatos de imágenes, dentro de esos se encuentra el TIFF